# Kendo ui checkbox bind

Tags: asp.net, linq, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

[User Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/550qQ.png)I have a Kendogrid that displays roles. When you click on edit of the role it opens a pop up window with multiple tabs. On one of the tab i have Users . This tab displays the list of all the users and a checkbox which is checked if the user has that role.
 Now when i check the checkbox of other User that role must be assigned me that user and save in the database. But how do i call a method in the service on the Onclick event of the checkbox or is there any other way.

The error iam getting is when i click on checkbox it says the addRoleUsr() is undefined. addRoleUsr() is defined in the service.Below is my grid definition.

Fron the picture attached when i click on a user the changes must be saved on the grid.

Thanks

```
 function editEventGrid() {
        editDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    return JSON.parse(response.d); // ASMX services return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. 
                },
                model: {// define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                    id: "UserId",
                    fields: {
                        FirstName: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                        UserId: { editable: true, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                        RoleId: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                            }
                },
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Services/ErpNowServices.asmx/getUsersRoles", //specify the URL which data should return the records. This is the Read method of the Products.asmx service.
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web service to serialize JSON
                    type: "POST", //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for ASMX
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: getSearchCriteria()
                },
                update: {
                    url: "/Services/ErpNowServices.asmx/UpdateUsers",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if ((type == "read") || (type == "update") || (type == "destroy")) {
                        console.log('parameterMap: data => ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                        return JSON.stringify(data);                            
                    } else {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        userGrid = $("#Users").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: editDS,
            height: 450,
            //dataBound: onDataBound,
            pageable: false,
            sortable: true,
            binding: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            editable: "inline",
            autoSync: true,

            columns: [
               {
                 field: "FirstName",
                 title: "FirstName",
                 headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">FirstName</span>',
                 attributes: {
                     style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                 }
               },
                                 {
                   field: "UserId",
                   title: "UserId",
                   headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">UserId</span>',
                   attributes: {
                       style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                   }
               },
               {

                   //title :"Check",
                   template: kendo.template("<input type='checkbox'  # if(RoleId){ # checked #} # onclick='addRoleUsr()'/>"),
                  // template: "<input type=\"checkbox\" # if(Rolename){ # checked #} # />",
                   attributes: {
                       style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"
                   }
               },

        ],
            editable: true,
        }).data('kendoGrid');
```

}

Comment: Please complete your question before posting it

Comment: Updated  can you please check it now

Comment: `addRoleUsr` ain't defined anywhere.  Are you missing some code?

Comment: that is defined in the service. my question is on clickcking or check or uncheck the checkbox how do we update the users grid. I wrote UpdateUsers on update but its not calling

Comment: calling dataGrid.sync() will do the trick

Comment: Where i  need to write this